# How to filter images smaller than an interested size in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

Does any know any efficient method? Say I am not interested any image smaller than 200x400 pixels. How to filter this list?

Comment: Im not sure any `find` option can be used, Will likely have to parse yourself with `identify` / `convert`

Comment: What tool are you using to get picture size?

Comment: It depends on what image format you are using, but `file` will output the size of some (like PNG).

Comment: What file format? Are you asking how to determine the size, or how to produce a list of files that satisfy the criteria?

Comment: @EvilGenius: I simply use ‘identify’ to check size

Comment: @WilliamPursell. I am asking how to produce a list of files satisfying the criterion. My file formats are jpg gif and tif.

Comment: What do you want to do with images that are smaller in only one dimension (e.g. 199x600 or 400x399)?

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
for F in *.jpg *.gif *.tif; do
    identify "$F"
done | awk '{ split($3, wh, /x/); } wh[1] >= 200 && wh[2] >= 400 { print $1; }'
```

Or:

```
find -type f -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*\.(jpg|gif|tif)$' -exec identify {} \; | awk '{ split($3, wh, /x/); } wh[1] >= 200 && wh[2] >= 400 { print $1; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `identify` and `gawk`

```
identify image.jpg | gawk '{match($0, /([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/, val); if (val[1] > 1000 && val[2] > 200) print $1}'
```